# Android Call log date convertion

Tags: android, date, logging, format, call

I have a call log backup from my Android mobile phone, and I'm trying to know the date & time of the calls.

The log says:

```
<HTCCALLOG>
new=1
numbertype=3
duration=28
number=PERSON'S PHONE NUMBER
type=1
_id=1853
numberlabel=null
name=PERSON'S NAME
date=1333119990954
```

Here's the problem. When I try to converto do Date Time (I'm using .Net's CSsharp), I got the following date **02/01/0001 01:01:51**, which of course is not the valid date of the call.

Trying to convert today's date and time to a long number from UTC format, I got **130134760479804654** which is a larger number than those in the log file.

Could someone points me what I'm doing wrong? Following is the code.

```
    long datelong = long.Parse("1333119793100");
    DateTime date = new DateTime(datelong, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0}\n{1}", today.ToFileTimeUtc(), datelong);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know too much of Unix word. Googleing a little, I found that this is the 'epoch' time, so I found out a convertion function:

```
public DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return epoch.AddSeconds(unixTime);
}
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
+998999431294</phoneNumber><dateTime>1624939282459</dateTime><callDuration>15</callDuration><logType>2</logType></callLog><callLog><phoneNumber>+998937031331</phoneNumber><dateTime>1624939219493</dateTime>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.